# Xcode 6.3 builds all swift files twice

Tags: xcode, swift

I just upgraded to Xcode 6.3, and am attempting to reduce the compile time to something manageable. I have ~120 swift files/classes in my project and it's taking 2-3 minutes to compile. My project also has two test targets: `UnitTests` and `AutomatedTests`.

Here's a snapshot of what's going on when I build:
[image]

Under each of those "Compile Swift source files" it compiled every single Swift file. I watched it as it happened.

Why would it be compiling everything twice, and how do I stop it?

**- Edit -**

@matt points out that it's building once for each architecture. I'm assuming this isn't necessary for development (running in simulator). Any suggestions on how to only build appropriate architectures for the target device?

Comment: Because it compiles them once for 32-bit and again for 64-bit?

Comment: @matt Bingo. Once for `arm64` and `armv7`.

Comment: Did you try changing the build setting that governs this? It's called Build Active Architecture Only.

Comment: That worked! I was building on a new custom config that was copied from `Release`, so it had inherited that setting.

Comment: Of course, now it _still_ takes too long to compile... Half of "a long time" is still "a pretty long time"!

Comment: @matt You should get credit for this; your comment should be an answer below that can be upvoted and accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: @JoshBrown I said nothing but what was trivially obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the **Build Active Architecture Only** setting for Debug and any other non-Release configuration from **No** to **Yes**. You want it to be **Yes** when you build for distribution, but otherwise having it set to **No** means your files won't be compiled twice.

Comment: I am confused, I guessed you meant: You want it to be NO when you build for distribution, but otherwise having it set to YES means your files won't be compiled twice. Debug should be YES and Release should be NO. Right?

Comment: I already have this setting set to Yes. What's odd is that it builds once for the simulator but twice for a real device.